# Get content of <div> using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I had used a JQuery plugin DialogExtend [link](https://github.com/ROMB/jquery-dialogextend)

On button click a dialog is opening. I have a div tag with some content. How can I load content of that div into the following script(in place of line no. 3)

```
$(function(){
 $("#my-button").click(function(){
  $("<div>This is content</div>")
    .dialog({ "title" : "My Dialog" })
    .dialogExtend({
      "maximizable" : true,
      "dblclick" : "maximize",
      "icons" : { "maximize" : "ui-icon-arrow-4-diag" }
    });
 });
```

});

html content want to load on that line:

```
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p></div>
```

I don't know much about jQuery, I only use plugins as required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
$(function(){
$("#my-button").click(function(){
  $("#dialog")
    .dialog({ "title" : "My Dialog" })
    .dialogExtend({
      "maximizable" : true,
      "dblclick" : "maximize",
      "icons" : { "maximize" : "ui-icon-arrow-4-diag" }
    });
 });
```

Comment: No,it is not working. After doing this, dialog is not getting pop out.

Comment: UPDATE:
Hey thanks. It is working. There was an unnecessary tag due to which dialog was not popping out.

Answer (score 0):

In this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BreMW/1060/)
you can see that your javascript (jquery) code is ok and working fine.

Maybe you don't understand how to bind it with the html, so pay attention to the **html**:

```
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
 <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p></div> 
<button id="my-button">Button</button>
```

also check your resources files (jquery & jquery UI)